# Silex second form behind first form

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, silex

What I want to do is quite simple. I have a first form. When this form is submitted, I have another form. When this second form is submitted, I want execute somes actions.

So here is my controller simplified:

```
$app->post('/path', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    $app['request'] = $request;

    $token = $app['security.token_storage']->getToken();
    if (null !== $token) {
        $user = $token->getUser();


        // First form
        $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(FormType::class)
        ->add('field_form1', TextType::class, [
            'required' => true,
        ])
        ->getForm();


        // Second form
        $formcb = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(FormType::class)
        ->add('field_form2', TextType::class, [
            'required' => true,
        ])
        ->getForm();


        // When second form is submitted
        $formcb->handleRequest($request);

        if($formcb->isSubmitted() && $formcb->isValid()) {
            // isValid is never true

            $data = $formcb->getData();
        }


        // When first form is submitted
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();

            switch ($data["paiementType"]) {
                [...]

                case 'mycase':
                    // Render of the second form
                    return $app['twig']->render('page2.twig', [
                        'form' => $formcb->createView(),
                    ]);

                default: break;
            }
        }

        // Render of the first form
        return $app['twig']->render('page1.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);

    }

})->bind('path');
```

But,

- No problems for the first form, it works well.
- The second form seems to have already been validated when it is render, because the fields errors message are display on the form.
- When I submit the second form, I never enter in the if($formcb->isSubmitted() && $formcb->isValid()) { clause, because isValid is never true... However, the form is submitted...

So I don't know what is wrong, maybe it is not the good way to render a form behind another form...

Comment: Mind sharing some twig code, or more specifically opening and closing for both forms, although it seems quite strange, considering you're rendering your template with only the first form being assigned?